# OnClientClick prevent page submission if validation errors

Tags: javascript, vb.net, onclientclick

I've written a JavaScript function which validates form input and highlights the input fields and displays any error messages, which I have tested and all works fine.

I have called this function from the OnClientClick attribute of an asp:Button tag. However, if the JavaScript function determines there to be validation errors, I want to stop the form from submitting. How do I do this?

I am a VB.NET newbie, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

ASPX

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Save Changes" runat="server" OnClientClick="validateEMI();" />
```

JavaScript

```
function validateEMI() {

     // a big bunch of validation checks...

     if (errorOnForm == true) {
         document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = errorMsg;
         return;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (errorOnForm == true) {
     document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = errorMsg;
     return false;
}
```

return false;

EDIT: and `validateEMI` should be hooked with `onsubmit` event

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried the 'return false', but it still submits the form after the error message has appeared.

Comment: You need to couple this with `OnClientClick =  "return validateEMI();"`

Comment: Thanks. The 'return false' and 'return validateEMI();' seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

use `stopPropagation`

```
function validateEMI(event) {
     event.stopPropagation()
     // a big bunch of validation checks...

     if (errorOnForm == true) {
         document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = errorMsg;
         return;
     }
}
```

Comment: What if the validation is successful? We probably only want to `stopPropagation` if `errorOnForm === false`.

Comment: Can someone please explain what the 'event' parameter is? thanks.

Comment: @Gareth See [Event: DOM Event interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event#DOM_Event_interface) on MDN.